# Group input into JSON dictionaries by a column in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I need your help in solving this issue using Shell on Unix.

### Input: Has 3 columns delimited by comma with a header row

City, Status, ID
Boston, Active, 1
Chicago, Expired,9
Boston, Active,3
Boston, Active,5
Chicago, Expired,6
Chicago, Disabled,4

### Desired output

{"id" : [ "1","3","5"],"PROPS" : { "STATUS" : "Active"}}
{"id" : [ "9","6"],"PROPS" : { "STATUS" : "Expired"}}
{"id" : [ "4"],"PROPS" : { "STATUS" : "Disabled"}}

If you notice above , the requirement is to group by City and Status and concatenate the ID values and put it inside the [] while just populating the Status in the {}. 
 e.g. from the 1st output row is [ "1","3","5"] and { "STATUS" : "Active"} which basically is the for Active records of Boston.

Can anyone please help me with the commands for this?

I tried using the following command,

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1{if(a[$1","$2]){a[$1","$2]=a[$1","$2]","$3} else { a[$1","$2]=$3}} END {for (i in a) {print i"|"a[i]}}'<br/>
```

But I am stuck at the print statement to get the output in the desired format.

Comment: Something like For all combinations City and Status (cut -d"," -f1,2 | sort -u), show we the status and all id's with this combination ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?  This seems like a good fit for `perl` or `awk`, or if you want straight shell you might want to start with a multi-field sort (`man sort`) to get cities and statuses in a predictable order.

Comment: @WalterA. That is correct.

Comment: @StephenP: Edited my post to add what I have tried so far

Comment: `jq` is the obvious Right Tool For The Job, if your desired output is JSON. And, in fact, we have a close relative showing how to do this with jq: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897445/jq-group-by-property-in-array

Comment: **Grouping** is easy to do with only built-in shell tools. **Generating output that's guaranteed to be valid JSON from arbitrary inputs** is not, and calls for [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) or [`jsawk`](https://github.com/micha/jsawk)... or, yes, Python.

Answer (score 2):

***Python*** solution:

```
import csv, collections, json

with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)   # read csv content into dict-like object
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        # accumulating ids for each `City-Status` group 
        d[row['City'] + '-' + row['Status']].append(row['ID']) 

for k,v in d.items():
    print(json.dumps({"id": v, "PROPS": {"STATUS": k.split('-')[1]}}))
```

The output:

```
{"id": ["9", "6"], "PROPS": {"STATUS": "Expired"}}
{"id": ["1", "3", "5"], "PROPS": {"STATUS": "Active"}}
{"id": ["4"], "PROPS": {"STATUS": "Disabled"}}
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

It can be slightly rearranged to run at the command line.

### ----------

Alternative ***awk*** + ***jq*** solution:

```
awk -F", *" 'NR>1{k=$1 SUBSEP $2; (!a[k])? a[k]=$3 : a[k]=a[k] OFS $3}
     END{ for(i in a) { split(i,b,SUBSEP); print b[2],a[i] }}' OFS="," yourfile.csv 
 | jq -R -n -c ' inputs 
       | split(",") as $item 
       | {"id": $item[1:], "PROPS":{"STATUS": $item[0]}}'
```

The output:

```
{"id":["1","3","5"],"PROPS":{"STATUS":"Active"}}
{"id":["4"],"PROPS":{"STATUS":"Disabled"}}
{"id":["9","6"],"PROPS":{"STATUS":"Expired"}}
```

Comment: Thank you but the solution we want is with shell scripting. I really appreciate your Python solution and will save it for future.

Comment: You don't even need `python -c`, you can put `#!/usr/bin/python` in the python source file and `chmod +x` it.

Comment: @StephenP: Yes, if the script's _sole_ purpose is to perform the task in the question; if it is to be _embedded_ in a larger shell script, then you need `python -c` with a multi-line string (e.g., a here-doc).

Answer (score 1):

Given a shell variable defined as follows:

```
s='City, Status, ID
Boston, Active, 1
Chicago, Expired,9
Boston, Active,3
Boston, Active,5
Chicago, Expired,6
Chicago, Disabled,4'
```

the following code:

```
jq -c -n -R '
  # helper function: trim leading and trailing whitespace
  def trimq: if type == "string" then sub("^ +";"") | sub(" +$";"") else . end;    

  # for each line, split by commas, and pass each piece through trimq
  [inputs | split(",") | [.[] | trimq]][1:]  ## ...note that [1:] skips the header.

  # then, add the ID to a dict keyed by the status
  | reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[$item[1]] += [$item[2]])

  # and transform from this simpler output form into the one requested in the question
  | to_entries     ## split into a list of dicts with "key" and "value" attributes
  | .[] as $entry  ## and assign each of those in turn to $entry
  | {"id": $entry.value, "PROPS": {"STATUS": $entry.key}}

' <<<"$s"
```

properly emits:

```
{"id":["1","3","5"],"PROPS":{"STATUS":"Active"}}
{"id":["9","6"],"PROPS":{"STATUS":"Expired"}}
{"id":["4"],"PROPS":{"STATUS":"Disabled"}}
```

Note that the `trimq` helper, and the code that applies it, is only necessary if your real data is as messy (in terms of whitespace surrounding the `,`s) as that given in the question.

Comment: Thank you Charles Duffy. This is a great solution and I will explore jq further . Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

You used awk as your example so I thought maybe an awk solution would be good:

```
awk -F"," '
function escape(s) { sub(/"/, "\\\"", s); return s }
function lquote(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]*/, "\"", s); return s }
function rquote(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]*$/, "\"", s); return s }
function quote(s)  { return rquote(lquote(escape(s))) }
NR>1{
  key=quote($1)","quote($2);
  data[key]=data[key]?data[key]","quote($3):quote($3);
}
END{
  for (key in data)
  {
    split(key,keys,",");
    print "{\"id\":["data[key]"],\"PROPS\":{\"STATUS\":"keys[2]"}}"
  }
}' data.csv
```

It's mostly the same as yours except I trim the input so that you don't need to worry about spaces after the commas making a difference and the string I print looks like what you wanted - one separate JSON object for each city/status pair (except the JSON is handmade unlike the awesome jq solution).

Comment: With respect to the `quote()` function -- does this make any effort to escape literal quotes found in the input data? If we had an input line with a status of, say, `Error["foo"]`, would the `"`s be properly escaped such that the output is well-formed JSON?

Comment: Jerry - Thank you so much. this is exactly what I wanted. Many thanks!

Comment: @Jerry - While your solution works great there is just one thing that is missing here. Is there a way we can tweak the code to add double quotes in front of IDs like shown in the output example above?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  No it doesn't pretend to be a full JSON solution.  That is something I will try to fix but it is like opening a can of worms.  The right answer is to use something that can do JSON properly like you did - generating handmade JSON is fragile by definition...